# Existence of an epimorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, monomorphisms, epimorphisms

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F$ such that dim$_F(V)>$dim$_F(W)$. Is it true that

1. an epimorphism $f:V \rightarrow W$ exists?
2. a monomorphism $f:V \rightarrow W$ does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Choose basis $\{v_1,..,v_n\}$ to $V$ and $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ to $W$ where $n>m$.
Then for the epimorphism part you can just take, 
$$f(v_i)=w_i,\quad 1\leq i\leq m, \quad f(v_k)=0, m+1\leq k\leq n.$$
It easy to show that this is epimorphism.

On the other hand, for any $f:V\rightarrow W$ the imeges 
$$\{f(v_1),...,f(v_n)\}$$
are lineary dependent, and hence the kernal of $f$ is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.  $V\cong \Bbb F^n$ and $W\cong \Bbb F^m$ where $n\gt m$.

The first claim is satisfied by $f(v_1,\dots, v_n)=(v_1,\dots,  v_m)$.

The second follows from the fact that, if there were a monomorphism from $V$ to $W$, then it would be an embedding of $V$ into $W$, which would violate that $V$ has greater dimension than $W$.